# Unwanted page reload in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ajax, safari

I program C ++, but I'm weak in javascripts. I am developing a single-purpose device with weight sensors. I transfer data via WiFi ESP822, I create a web page there. On a mobile device and display via Internet browser on a smartphone or tablet. The laptop is also fine. I found and used the following javascript code to change the data on the display without the need for a reload page.

Everything works perfectly. Except for Safari.
Safari not only changes the data on the page, but reload the entire page.
Can anyone advise me please? The aim is to achieve universality.
Script is in head of page.

Video ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1NmXTbEpGU

Thank you for any advice

Milan

```
<script>
setInterval(loadDoc,300);
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById(\"webpage\").innerHTML =this.responseText
      };
    };
    xhttp.open(\"GET\", \"/calc\", true);
    xhttp.send();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, the video you have linked to is private.

Comment: sorry friend, corrected :)

Comment: you use `setInterval()` witch gets executed every 300ms. So you call `loadDoc()` evey 300ms and it sets your innerHTML to the responsetext. also, XMLHttpRequest() is kinda old. we use `fetch()`

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I need to update the data every 300ms. Without refresh whole page. It looks like this on chrome... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnlHPzzZZzo. I want that on Safari too. I'm weak in Javascript, I don't know fetch ()